# QtQuick and PySide6 , trouble getting PySide6 model to generate QML string for driver file

Tags: python, qt, qml, qt-quick, pyside6

I have a class (tableView.py) that is intended to generate a QML string returned by the qml() function

```
class tableView:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self._items = items

    @QtCore.Property(str, constant=True)
    def qml(self):
        #itemList = self._items
        return f"""
        Column{{
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                y: 180
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow1
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: 180
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row1Rectangle
                    x: tableRow1.x
                    y: tableRow1.height + 1
                    width: tableRow1.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 1"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 2"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 3"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}
                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow2
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow1.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row2Rectangle
                    x: tableRow1.x
                    y: tableRow2.height + 1
                    width: tableRow1.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 4"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 5"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 6"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow1.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}
                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow3
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow2.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row3Rectangle
                    x: tableRow2.x
                    y: tableRow3.height + 1
                    width: tableRow2.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 7"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow2.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 8"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow2.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 9"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow2.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}
                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow4
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow3.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row4Rectangle
                    x: tableRow3.x
                    y: tableRow4.height + 1
                    width: tableRow3.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 10"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 11"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 12"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow5
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow4.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row5Rectangle
                    x: tableRow4.x
                    y: tableRow5.height + 1
                    width: tableRow4.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 13"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 14"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 15"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow6
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow5.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row6Rectangle
                    x: tableRow5.x
                    y: tableRow6.height + 1
                    width: tableRow5.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 16"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 17"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 18"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow7
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow6.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row7Rectangle
                    x: tableRow6.x
                    y: tableRow7.height + 1
                    width: tableRow6.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 19"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 20"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 21"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow8
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow7.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row8Rectangle
                    x: tableRow7.x
                    y: tableRow8.height + 1
                    width: tableRow7.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 22"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 23"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 24"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}


                }} 
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow9
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow8.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row9Rectangle
                    x: tableRow8.x
                    y: tableRow9.height + 1
                    width: tableRow8.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 25"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 26"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 27"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            Row {{
                
                x: 224
                width: 450
                height: 26
                spacing: 20


                Rectangle {{
                    id: tableRow10
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    y: tableRow9.y + 5
                    
                    Rectangle {{
                    id: row10Rectangle
                    x: tableRow9.x
                    y: tableRow10.height + 1
                    width: tableRow8.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#d6d7d7"
                    }}

                    Text{{
                        text: "testing 28"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 10
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 29"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + 166
                    }}

                    Text{{
                    
                        text: "testing 30"
                        color: "black"
                        x: tableRow3.x + (2*166) + 30
                    }}

                }}  
            }}
            
    }}
```

In main.py, I'm trying to generate an instance of this class, and then get a qml_string which I can then use to load a component into the main interface window outputted by main.py:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QByteArray

from tableView import *


from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

table = tableView([])
qml_string = str(table.qml)



engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')

#Trouble with this line of code:
#engine.loadData(qml_string.encode())



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Problem is, there is an Exception being thrown with the qml_string variable which prevents it from being used for generating the component. I would like to know how to appropriately generate the qml string from my custom class, and then use that qml_string to load into my main.qml

I've tried testing for exceptions to see what error is being thrown:

```
try:
    # Try to get the QML string from the table object
    qml_string = table.qml()
    if isinstance(qml_string, str):
        # The qml_string variable is a valid string, so we can use it
        pass
    else:
        # The qml_string variable is not a string, so we need to handle the error
        qml_string = None
except Exception as e:
    # An exception was raised while trying to get the QML string from the table object
    qml_string = None
```

An exception was raised while trying to get QML string from the object is what I have been receiving, but I can't figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Also generating QML string is extremly inefficient, you should prefer using models and delegates...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the tableView class definition. Since you're using @QtCore.Property, the class should inherit from QObject, and the constructor must properly initialize the base type.

```
class tableView(QObject):
    def __init__(self, items):
        super().__init__()
        self._items = items

    @QtCore.Property(str, constant=True)
    def qml(self):
        ...
```

After modification, the qml property should return a valid string.